# How to center three js object into DIV:

Tags: javascript, three.js

I cannot center three js object into DIV

[Here is my code](https://jsfiddle.net/r1jd29ct/):

```js
    import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/pin/three@v0.128.0-iDyvDZdRCoyR9DXa2rWg/mode=imports,min/optimized/three.js';
     
    const container = document.getElementById("canvas");
    // const selected = document.querySelector("#canvas");
    // document.body.appendChild(container);
    
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( container.offsetWidth, container.offsetWidth );
    
    // renderer.setSize( item.clientWidth, item.clientHeight );
    
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    
    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
    const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( cube );
    
    camera.position.z = 5;
    
    const animate = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    
        cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
        cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
    
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
    };
    
    animate();
```

And that's how the problem looks:

[image]

Object just going outside the DIV:

[image]

I dont know why it happens. I'm trying to fix this a couple of days and try a lot of ways and it still does not work. Probably I don't understand something and need your help...

Answer (score 1):

I guess i solved the problem. I just delete padding of the #canvas in css and its now work as expected.

[image: now thats how it looks like:]

Comment: When you post an answer to your own question, please explain how did you solve it. Otherwise it's not valueable at all.

Comment: Okay, but i guess i explained. The problem was because i was using padding, when i delete that, problem was solved.